# Why is Google Earth changing KML polygon coordinates?

Tags: xml, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml, google-earth

My goal is to be able to draw a shaded polygon over a defined area in google earth using a KML file. I have created a KML document with one placemark and a polygon with the desired coordinates and am able to import the file into Google My maps and display the polygon. However, when I open the same file with google earth the coordinates seem to be parsed differently and the polygon is not correct ( see image). Is there something I have missed in my KML file that is causing google earth to do this?

These are the original file coordinates.

```
<coordinates>
    149.02126, -36.489864, 100
    149.3816, -36.31477, 100
    149.25783, -36.134285, 100
    148.9647, -36.4074, 100
    149.02126, -36.489864, 100
</coordinates>
```

If I copy the polygon from google earth and paste it to a text file as KML I get the following coordinates

```
<coordinates>
    149.02126,-36.489864,100 
    149.3816,0,0 
    -36.31477,100,0 
    149.25783,-36.134285,100 
    148.9647,-36.4074,100 
    149.02126,-36.489864,100 
</coordinates>
```

Complete Original KML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
   <Document>
      <Style id="examplePolyStyle">
         <PolyStyle>
            <color>7f0000ff</color>
            <colorMode>random</colorMode>
            <fill>1</fill>
            <outline>1</outline>
         </PolyStyle>
      </Style>
      <Placemark>
         <name>ID: AU201502070705001Issued: 2015-02-07T07:53:00.000Z</name>
         <description>Begins: 2015-02-07T07:53:00.000ZEnds: 2015-02-07T08:38:00.000Z</description>
         <styleUrl>#examplePolyStyle</styleUrl>
         <Polygon>
            <outerBoundaryIs>
               <LinearRing>
                  <coordinates>149.02126, -36.489864, 100 149.3816, -36.31477, 100 149.25783, -36.134285, 100 148.9647, -36.4074, 100 149.02126, -36.489864, 100</coordinates>
               </LinearRing>
            </outerBoundaryIs>
         </Polygon>
      </Placemark>
   </Document>
</kml>
```

Complete KML file copied from Google Earth

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Document>
    <name>Latest_Single_noCommaNoSpaces.kml</name>
    <Style id="examplePolyStyle">
        <PolyStyle>
            <color>7f0000ff</color>
            <colorMode>random</colorMode>
        </PolyStyle>
    </Style>
    <Placemark>
        <name>ID: AU201502070705001Issued: 2015-02-07T07:53:00.000Z</name>
        <description>Begins: 2015-02-07T07:53:00.000ZEnds: 2015-02-07T08:38:00.000Z</description>
        <styleUrl>#examplePolyStyle</styleUrl>
        <gx:balloonVisibility>1</gx:balloonVisibility>
        <Polygon>
            <outerBoundaryIs>
                <LinearRing>
<coordinates>
    149.02126,-36.489864,100 
    149.3816,0,0 
    -36.31477,100,0 
    149.25783,-36.134285,100 
    148.9647,-36.4074,100 
    149.02126,-36.489864,100 
</coordinates>
                </LinearRing>
            </outerBoundaryIs>
        </Polygon>
    </Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
```

[image: Screenshot of polygon in Google Maps]

[image: Screenshot of same polygon in Google Earth]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original KML coordinates have spaces in the tuples, [that is not valid](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#coordinates) (spaces *separate* tuples).

from [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#coordinates):

> **`<coordinates>`(required)**
>   Four or more tuples, each consisting of floating point values for longitude, latitude, and altitude. The altitude component is optional. **Do not include spaces within a tuple.** The last coordinate must be the same as the first coordinate. Coordinates are expressed in decimal degrees only.

```
<coordinates>149.02126, -36.489864, 100 149.3816, -36.31477, 100 149.25783, -36.134285, 100 148.9647, -36.4074, 100 149.02126, -36.489864, 100</coordinates>
```

should be:

```
<coordinates>149.02126,-36.489864,100 149.3816,-36.31477,100 149.25783,-36.134285,100 148.9647,-36.4074,100 149.02126,-36.489864,100</coordinates>
```